# Div inside a href with ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to integrate a design that includes this kind of menu item:

```
<div class="cell first">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="m_account" class="img"></div>
        <div class="menu_item">my account</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

How can I make an `ActionLink` to provide this kind of code?

I sometimes use areas so some links must have `new {area = "MyAccount"}` attribute.

Thanks.

Comment: you can put @URL.Action("ActionName") in the href

Comment: Why do you use pure html like your example. No need to use actionLink. Also, If you want you can write your own htmlHelper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<div class="cell first">
   <a href="@url.Action("YourAction")">
        <div id="m_account" class="img"></div>
       <div class="menu_item">my account</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no link in this HTML that an `ActionLink` can replace :

```
<div class="cell first">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="m_account" class="img"></div>
    <div class="menu_item">my account</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

if you wanted to do something like this:

```
<a href="myAccount/Login" class="img" id="m_account"/></a>
```

that would be written like:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = "m_account", @class = "img" })
```

you just put any attribute name and values in the second part of the `ActionLink`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Html.ActionLink`, use `Url.Action`

```
<div class="cell first">
  <a href="@(Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"))">
    <div id="m_account" class="img"></div>
    <div class="menu_item">my account</div>
  </a>
</div>
```